# Multiple node.js requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, promise

My controller is using the `request` package to make server-side HTTP requests to another API. My question is how can I make MULTIPLE of these requests? Here is my current code:

** UPDATED CODE **

```
module.exports = function (req, res) {
var context = {};
request('http://localhost:3000/api/single_project/' + req.params.id, function (err, resp1, body) {
    context.first = JSON.parse(body);
    request('http://localhost:3001/api/reports/' + req.params.id, function (err, resp2, body2) {
        context.second = JSON.parse(body2); //this line throws 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token u' error
        res.render('../views/project', context);
    });
});
```

};

I need to make two more of those calls and send the data returned from it to my template...

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Simple solution

Nest request calls. This is how you can handle the dependency between requests. Just make sure your parameters are unique across scopes if needed.

```
module.exports = function (req, res) {
    var context = {};
    request('http://localhost:3000/api/1st', function (err, resp1, body) {
        var context.first = JSON.parse(body);
        request('http://localhost:3000/api/2nd', function (err, resp2, body) {
            context.second = JSON.parse(body);
            request('http://localhost:3000/api/3rd', function (err, resp3, body) {
                context.third = JSON.parse(body);
                res.render('../views/project', context);
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Is this technique blocking or async?

Comment: @user1547174 This is async. The call backs fire when the response is returned.

Comment: @t3dodson this is executed serially and one failure in chain leads to failure of whole chain, it is better to use promises as it helps to avoud heavy nesting

Comment: Talking about a async. Do yourself a favour, avoid this callback hell, and give the npm module [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) a spin.

Answer (score 2):

```
function makePromise (url) {
  return Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

      request(url, function(err, resp, body) {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(JSON.parse(body));
      });

  });
}

module.exprts = function (req, res) {
  let urls = ['http://localhost:3000/api/1st', 
              'http://localhost:3000/api/2st',
              'http://localhost:3000/api/3st'].map((url) => makePromise(url));

  Promise
    .all(urls)
    .then(function(result) {
      res.render('../views/project', {'first': result[0], 'second': result[1], 'third': result[2]});
    })
    .catch(function(error){
      res.end(error);
    });
}
```

You can use `Promise` lib in latest nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way if you use [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) promise library:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var request = Promise.promisify(require('request'));

module.exports = function (req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  var urls = [
   'http://localhost:3000/api/1st/' + id,
   'http://localhost:3000/api/2st/' + id,
   'http://localhost:3000/api/3st/' + id
  ];

  var allRequests = urls.map(function(url) { return request(url); });

  Promise.settle(allRequests)
    .map(JSON.parse)
    .spread(function(json1, json2, json3) {
      res.render('../views/project', { json1: json1 , json2: json2, json3: json3  });
    });
});
```

it executes all requests even if one (or more) fails